# Using Power Manager

Tags: java, android

My app sets an alarm.   While waiting for the alarm my phone closes the screen.   When the alarm sounds the screen is dark so I press the power key and the screen lights up but I now have to touch the Lock button to access the app interface.   I would prefer that the Lock has been disposed off when the user responds to the alarm so I tried to use the power manager.  The alarm receiver starts a new activity so I initialised the power manager in the onCreate for this activity.    However this causes a force close error.  I call the power manager as follows

```
   PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)cText.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
   PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK , TAG);
   wl.acquire();
```

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did add the uses permisson for power mananger in your manifest?

Answer (score 3):

Since the person asking the question states that he "has to touch the lock" button I assume that he is speaking about the Key Guard. (Pattern, Pin etc). You cannot use the PowerManager API to disable this. Instead you should diable the KeyGuard

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = 
      (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock lock = 
       keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
lock.disableKeyguard();
```

To My knowledge, this is the correct way to disable the Screen Lock.

You also need this Permission

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take wl in Application context so once its initlize and set back to that and after that when you release that you will set null and check that it again if its null than init again other wise take it as it is.